# mysql concat csv from two columns into key pairs

Tags: mysql

I've a table in MySQL that contains two columns of comma-separated data (ugh!) which I need to reformat so the nth index of the first column value matches the nth index of the second column value

```
id   | col1        | col2
----------------------------------
1    | a,b,c,d     | a5,3e,7f48,943d44
```

the result would look like

```
results
--------------
a:a5
b:3e
c:7f48
d:943d44
```

concat, group_concat, find_in_set and so on don't seem to be up to the job; is there an equivalent function / procedure to php's array_combine()?

Comment: How many CSV items do you expect to be in each of the `col1` and `col2` records?  Is that number always known and fixed?  Note that there is no general way to do this with the core MySQL functions.

Comment: Stop putting comma-separated lists in SQL columns. Normalize your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general way to do this in MySQL without the help of a UDF or stored proc.  But, one approximation, with certain assumptions, would be to make use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ',', 1), ':', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2, ',', 1)) AS results
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ',', 2), ',', -1), ':',
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2, ',', 2), ',', -1))
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ',', 3), ',', -1), ':',
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2, ',', 3), ',', -1))
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, ',', -1), ':', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2, ',', -1))
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

This would work if you always have exactly 4 CSV items in each record.  If not, then we could still use this approach, but it would start to get really ugly.

If you expect to have more than one row of data, and you also want to sort the output, this can be accomplished by adding a computed column to the query, and doing an `ORDER BY` with that.  But in general, MySQL is not well equipped to be working with such CSV data.  Try to keep CSV out of your tables if possible.

Comment: I can see how ugly that gets, since the data has rows that contain way more fields in some rows. Normalising means changing the [third paty] software that relies on this ridiculous format. I think the best way forward for me will be to export, externally process, then re-import. Cheers for the answer

Comment: @frumbert Yeah...doing this outside of MySQL would probably be the easier option.